# How to loop through a table to make API call?

Tags: api, loops, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in my database that I need to loop through and make and API call. It's only three columns but about 300,000 rows. I need to grab all three columns and pass it in the `requests.get()` call.

Is there a way of doing that without putting into an RDD? Or if putting it into an RDD is the only way, how can it be done? Sorry a bit new to spark so I'm working on my own.